# Google App Engine Connected Android Registration with Endpoints Server FAILED

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to follow this guide to get an App Engine Connected Android Project working.  However, when I try to run my Android application and register, the Registration with Google Cloud Messaging succeeds, but the Registration with Endpoints Server fails.

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae

I manually set the LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN = true in CloudEndpointUtils.java

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?  I have tried the suggestions in search results with no success.

```
Exception received when attempting to register with server at http://10.0.2.2:8888/_ah/api/
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8888) after 20000ms
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:832)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:964)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at com.finalproject.GCMIntentService.onRegistered(GCMIntentService.java:163)
    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.handleRegistration(GCMBaseIntentService.java:251)
    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:153)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

My screen on my phone looks similar to this:
[image]

Comment: If you found a solution to this problem, please share it.But am guessing this was because you didn't enable a couple of APIs in developers console.

Comment: I had to deploy the GAE side of the project, not run it locally.  That solved the problem.